# R - Most efficient way to remove all non-matched rows in a data.table rolling join (instead of 2-step procedure with semi join)

Tags: r, data.table

Currently solve this with a workaround, but I would like to know if there is a **more efficient** way.

See below for exemplary data:

```
library(data.table)
library(anytime)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(batchtools)

# Lookup table 
Date <- c("1990-03-31", "1990-06-30", "1990-09-30", "1990-12-31",
          "1991-03-31", "1991-06-30", "1991-09-30", "1991-12-31")
period <- c(1:8)
metric_1 <- rep(c(2000, 3500, 4000, 100000), 2)
metric_2 <- rep(c(200, 350, 400, 10000), 2)
id <- 22

dt <- setDT(data.frame(Date, period, id, metric_1, metric_2))


# Fill and match table 2
Date_2 <- c("1990-08-30", "1990-02-28", "1991-07-31", "1991-09-30", "1991-10-31")
random <- c(10:14)
id_2 <- c(22,33,57,73,999)

dt_fill <- setDT(data.frame(EXCL_DATE, random, id_2))


# Convert date columns to type date
dt[ , Date := anydate(Date)]
dt_fill[ , Date_2 := anydate(Date_2)]
```

Now for the data wrangling. I want to get the most recent preceding data from `dt` (aka lookup table) into `dt_fill`. I do this with an easy 1-line rolling join like this.

```
# Rolling join
dt_res <- dt[dt_fill, on = .(id = id_2, Date = Date_2), roll = TRUE] 
# if not all id_2 present in id column in table 1, we get rows with NA
# I want to only retain the rows with id's that were originally in the lookup table
```

Then I end with a bunch of rows filled with `NAs` for the newly added columns that I would like to get rid of. I do this with a `semi-join`. I found outdated solutions to be quite hard to understand and settled for `batchtools::sjoin()` function which is essentially also a one liner.

```
dt_final <- sjoin(dt_res, dt, by = "id")
```

Is there a more efficient way of accomplishing a clean output result from a rolling join than by doing the rolling join first and then a semi-join with the original dataset. It is also not very fast for very long data sets. Thanks!

Comment: Abstracting from my particular case by building this "toy case" has just made me realise that I could maybe just do a filtering operation beforehand, no? 
What about ```dt_fill <- dt_fill[id_2 %in% dt[ , unique(id)]]```? That would align both data sets according to the ```id``` values found in ```dt```...

Comment: Yep that works. Another way to do a one liner is to use nomatch=0: `dt_res <- dt[dt_fill, on = .(id = id_2, Date = Date_2), roll = TRUE, nomatch=0]`.

Comment: From `data.table 1.12.0` the imho more intuitive "`nomatch = NULL` [...] does the same as `nomatch = 0L`"

Comment: That's great. I agree, that it is more easily readable! Thanks for your comment Henrik!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, there are two approaches I find that are both viable solutions.

**Solution 1**

First, proposed by lil_barnacle is an elegant one-liner that reads like following:

```
# Rolling join with nomtach-argument set to 0
dt_res <- dt[dt_fill, on = .(id = id_2, Date = Date_2), roll = TRUE, nomatch=0]
```

**Original approach**

Adding the `nomatch` argument and setting it to 0 like this `nomatch = 0`, is equivalent to doing the rolling join first and doing the semi-join thereafter.

```
# Rolling join without specified nomatch argument 
dt_res <- dt[dt_fill, on = .(id = id_2, Date = Date_2), roll = TRUE] 

# Semi-join required
dt_final <- sjoin(dt_res, dt, by = "id")
```

**Solution 2**

Second, the solution that I came up with was to 'align' both data sets before the rolling join by means of filtering by the 'joined variable' like so:

```
# Aligning data sets by filtering accd. to joined 'variable'
dt_fill <- dt_fill[id_2 %in% dt[ , unique(id)]]

# Rolling join without need to specify nomatch argument 
dt_res <- dt[dt_fill, on = .(id = id_2, Date = Date_2), roll = TRUE]
```